# What's the `z()` function in `stats` package of Python?

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

In section "Using filter() to identify outliers" of [Functional Python Programming - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/functional-python-programming-second-edition) by Steven F. Lott, page 106, there's the following code snippet:

```
from stats import mean, stdev, z
dist_data = list(map(dist, trip))
μ_d = mean(dist_data)
σ_d = stdev(dist_data)
outlier = lambda leg: z(dist(leg), μ_d, σ_d) > 3
print("Outliers", list(filter(outlier, trip)))
```

I googled around but found no `stats` package in Python. Some relevant stuff includes: [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) package since Python 3.4, and [stats.zscore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) function in scipy. But there's no `z()` function in these packages.

I also searched in the source code [repo](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Functional-Python-Programming-Second-Edition) of this book,
and didn't find above snippet.

Where to find and install this `stats` package?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading code from the page at https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/31830?

Comment: @Bill Bell, I've downloaded the code. They are the same with the code repo I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is very interesting. My assumption, the book was written in 2015 and republished in 2018. I guess there might be a chance of missing library file validation with the latest python.  However, I have visited https://pypi.org/project/stats and personally installed two versions of `stats` I couldn't find `z()` function. Finally, I tried `pip install stats==0.1a` which is not compatible for python3.x. I manually downloaded the code and looked for `z()` function, no luck!!

> stats.py is an 8-year-old script, not seeing much updates on it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like an older function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.z.html?highlight=z#scipy.stats.z

I am guessing you can try with the zscore function you found.

*edit: I am not saying it will work exactly the same... just that the name and implementation changed. I think you need to update your code if you want it to work... (like removing the mean and standard deviation)

Comment: Notice the parameters that function has, compared to the arguments passed to `z` in the code snippet above.

Comment: Indeed, it's different but it seems simpler now, you can remove the 2 additional arguments (mean and standard deviation).